# Why does a cURL request return a percent sign (%) with every request in ZSH?

Tags: curl, command-line, zsh

I've noticed that the return from any cURL request in ZSH ends in a `%`, for example:

```
$ curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number="555555555" -d message="hey"
=> { "success": true }%
```

Why is this character being added and is there a standard method for removing it?

note: ZSH is the only shell that I notice this occurring (tested in bash csh ksh sh tcsh zsh)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This is a zsh *feature* that prints a percent-and-newline after a command completes *if* that command does not already include a newline at the end of its output. If zsh did not do this, you would either not ever notice the fact that the command didn't print a newline - or you'd see zsh's command prompt *not* start on the margin and think it was a bug in zsh.

Tools like curl religiously print whatever results they get from the source and should never spontaneously print a newline without being asked to. I see this behaviour most often with curl. If you are coding a tool that uses curl, you do of course have the option of adding in a newline yourself.

I suggest not adding a newline unless you really have to. In the case where you really want to add a newline, you can use a separate tool (echo for example) - but the easiest with curl is the "write-out" option:

```
$ curl http://api.macvendors.com/0015c7   
Cisco Systems, Inc%     
$ curl -w '\n' http://api.macvendors.com/0015c7
Cisco Systems, Inc
$
```

From curl's man page:

> ```
>    -w, --write-out <format>
>           Make  curl  display  information  on stdout after a completed transfer. The format is a string that may contain plain text
>           mixed with any number of variables. The format can be specified as a literal "string", or you can have curl read the  for-
>           mat from a file with "@filename" and to tell curl to read the format from stdin you write "@-".
> ```

Comment: Sorry to revice an old thread. But any idea what this feature is called? It someohow got disabled for me recently and I cant figure out how to re-enable it

Comment: Found it, its `setopt PROMPT_CR`!

Comment: your answer `curl -w '\n' ...`works for me, thanks. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Try explicitly adding a newline \n to the message.