# printf adds mysterious trailing % character in zsh

Tags: printf, zsh

I want to print repeated `*` characters in zsh. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/1291990) has a solution that works in `bash`:

```sh
printf '*%.0s' {1..50}
```

However when I run that in `zsh`, I get this output:

```
**************************************************%
```

where the trailing `%` sign has inverted colors. This is mysterious to me and I want to know why that happens, and how do I avoid it?

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening, but it seems to be a display thing only. If you write that output to a file, and then `vim` the file, it won't be there.

Comment: @MikeFurlender Yes it is. I just tried that and it is in fact there in the file.

Comment: @MikeFurlender oh interesting. When you `vim` the file, it's not there, but when you `cat` the file it is. So there must be a character stored, but `vim` isn't showing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a cURL request return a percent sign (%) with every request in ZSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497038/why-does-a-curl-request-return-a-percent-sign-with-every-request-in-zsh)

Comment: @MichaelDorst It is not the case that there is a character but `vim` isn't showing it. Try this: `printf '*%.0s' {1..1} | wc -c` - the output is `1`

Comment: @MikeFurlender yes apparently zsh prints `%` with inverted colors and a newline in place of nothing, to show that there is no newline, but still allow the prompt to display correctly on the next line. Now that I know what it's doing, I'm a big fan of that feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a character, it's the lack of a character.

If the last line of output is not terminated (i.e. does not end with a newline character, `\n`), zsh shows a reverse-video `%` sign. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting.

The fix is to just output a terminating newline:

```
printf '*%.0s' {1..50}; echo
```

Comment: So `zsh` inserts `%` and a newline so that the prompt doesn't get printed at the end of the previous line, like it does in bash? That's actually really cool, I'm glad I learned this.